# How to forward streaming media (music ) in ios?

Tags: ios, swift

```
var url = NSURL(string: musicArr?.objectAtIndex(count) as! String)

    player = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
            self.view.addSubview(player.view)


    player.movieMediaTypes.rawValue
    player.prepareToPlay()
    player.play()
```

Using movie player , i am playing media from remote URL!

If I click on middle of the slider the mp3 should start from there.

Comment: And your question is what exactly? What does not work, what happens instead!?

Comment: @luk2302 , I have created a slider to show song's playback time.The thing I want is , when user clicks on middle of the slider the song(remote URL) should buffer and start playing.